# grammatical accuracy and meaning of the given sentences

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

How good are you at doing **things** when you're put on the spot?

How good are you at doing **something** when you're put on the spot?

Is the second one grammatically incorrect?
What's the difference in the meaning between the sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatical. The difference in meaning is extremely small.

I would say that the difference is in focus. If you say "things", this is general, and there is no particular focus. If you say "something", you are choosing to use a singular (you could also say "a thing") and in some way you are putting a focus on that single thing. But as I say, the difference is very slight.